# Popover image on hover bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, popover, onhover

I'm completely new to web technologies,
I have a table that retrieves data from a database and they are displayed with bootstrap table.

[Check out the interface image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FluG3.png)

I have usernames;
each username has their own image.
I have the images for every username stored online.
with the following naming:

```
username= 111
has an image with the name 111.jpg 
stored on localhost/images/111.jpg
```

What I want to achieve is when I hover over any username in the table, their image is displayed.

list-user.php file

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';

    $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users ")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $arrVal = array();

    $i=1;
    while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {

                    $name = array(
                            'num' => $i,
                            'user'=> $rowList['username'],                  
                        );      

                        array_push($arrVal, $name); 
        $i++;           
    }
         echo  json_encode($arrVal);        


    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

`

what matters from index.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var $table = $('#table');
         $table.bootstrapTable({
              url: 'list-user.php',
              search: true,
              pagination: true,
              buttonsClass: 'primary',
              showFooter: true,
              minimumCountColumns: 2,
              columns: [{
                  field: 'num',
                  title: '#',
                  sortable: true,
              },{
                  field: 'user',
                  title: 'Username',
                  sortable: true,
              },  ],

         });

</script>
```

Thats what I'm trying to accomplish something like this

[What I want to accomplish (IMAGE )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtMrz.jpg)

Comment: in your table you have a column for the image path?

Comment: I dont have any at the moment I have the images stored online because I dont have an idea how to implement this

Comment: The convention is to create a column for your image path and then pass that path with user information so you can display it in your html code

Comment: Ok i created a column for imgurl for each user what next?

Comment: you need to allow the user to insert his chosen image into the database then pass the image with user info and in your html can make the images `display: none` and only if the user hovers over it you will show the image .check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ipa9xAs_nTg)

Comment: I know how to display an img in php, I just need help to run it on my bootstrap table there should be a for loop & array

Comment: Yes you will have at least one loop since you have  more than one user in your data